# SSAS Cube Browsing not working after SQL 2008 CTP uninstall

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, cubes

I've had SQL 2005 & 2008 CTP installed side-by-side with no problems.

Recently uninstalled the CTP after it expired and now whenever I try to browse an analysis services cube in SSMS 2005 or VS 2005, I get the follwoing error:

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C4F9B80B-89F7-4800-9C26-504D6E692B2C} failed due to the following error: 80040154.**

I've tried re-installing Office Web Components but it's made no difference.  I've also installed SQL 2008 SSMS RTM and this has made no difference to VS or SSMS 2005.

When I try to browse from SSMS 2008 RTM I get this error:

**Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))**

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1):

This error plagued me for weeks, then I searched my registry backup and restored these:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{C4F9B80B-89F7-4800-9C26-504D6E692B2C}]
@="MarshalledToIStreamDataObject Class"
"AppID"="{B2463DC8-B3FA-4BEC-945E-60219DCC6FD8}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{C4F9B80B-89F7-4800-9C26-504D6E692B2C}\InprocServer32]
@="c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Bin\Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Helpers.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{C4F9B80B-89F7-4800-9C26-504D6E692B2C}\ProgID]
@="VsIntergrationNativeHelpers.Marshalle.1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{C4F9B80B-89F7-4800-9C26-504D6E692B2C}\VersionIndependentProgID]
@="VsIntergrationNativeHelpers.MarshalledT"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\VsIntergrationNativeHelpers.Marshalle.1\CLSID]
@="{C4F9B80B-89F7-4800-9C26-504D6E692B2C}"

Copy and paste them into notepad, save as a reg file (double click .reg file to import into registry) and restart - this solved my problem.

HTH,
Gaz